# Tensorflow Java RNN-LSTM reset state

Tags: java, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible to reset RNN-LSTM hidden state using Tensorflow Java API? I'm currently predicting using loaded model;

```
model = SavedModelBundle.load(MODEL_PATH, "serve");
outputs = model.session().runner().feed("input_layer", in).fetch("time_distributed/transpose_1:0").run();
```

but after some number of predictions I need to reset hidden LSTM state.
I need to call following Keras Python function on the loaded model

```
model.reset_states()
```

I need to use the `stateful=True` model and then resetting its state. Sending complete sequence and using `stateful=False` is not a solution for me because of performance issues.